# How align these views in my activity for all screen in android?

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout

I have a parent vertical linear layout.

In it around 4-5 horizontal linear layout.
In those a textView which is aligned at the left of the activity.
And a spinner which is aligned at the right of the activity.

Same no of textviews and spinners sorresponding to that.

I am setting margins according to a 3.5inch screen phone.

But it seems to get disturbed on bigger screens.

How do I make the alignment universal?

Comment: Post some pictures of how your layout looks on smaller and larger screens. What exactly do you want your layout to look like? It sounds like your horizontal `LinearLayout`s might not be spanning the entire width the of screen.

Comment: Post XML or any other code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use layout_gravity for both textview and spinner and be sure that the text view is wrap content. Text view left and spinner right layout_gravity . You can also give them slight left and right margins to be prettier . Also be sure that your horizontal layout width is match_parent.